# Does the name of the csr and private key file should match the domain name?

Tags: ssl, openssl, csr

I am confused about the name of file for private key and csr. I am using openssl to genearte private key, and then generate csr. Do the file names have to match the domain name?

My domain is, say, tropy.com, so do I have to name csr file as tropy.com.csr, or can I say april2014.csr?

Comment: The names of the private key and CSR files are arbitrary and can be what ever you want. That being said, it is helpful to have them organized by a naming convention so that it is clear what domain they belong to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My domain is, say, tropy.com, so do I have to name csr file as tropy.com.csr, or can I say april2014.csr?

No. The filenames are arbitrary. But its useful to keep them similarly named, especially if you have multiple domains and multiple certificates.

I usually use the following scheme:

- www-example-com-csr.pem
- www-example-com-key.pem
- www-example-com-cert.pem
- mail-example-com-csr.pem
- mail-example-com-key.pem
- mail-example-com-cert.pem